# What does a filter filter?

Tags: android, listview, filter, adapter, searchview

So I didn't how to say it better in my question. I have an SearchView and in its 'onQueryTextChange' method I'm setting a filter on my custom adapter. If I'm testing it and type something into the SearchView there is something filterd but it's quite random I guess.
The custom adapter has two TextViews and an ImageView so my question is: Which View will be used for filtering and how can I declare a which View should be used for filtering? Is this even possible?

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

So this is my code for the Search View

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);   
    View element = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chateintrag_layout, parent, false);                
    TextView user = element.findViewById(R.id.user);                                            
    TextView message = element.findViewById(R.id.lastmessage);
    user.setText(values[position]);                                                             
    DatenSpeichernUndLaden freund= new DatenSpeichernUndLaden();                                
    String[] lastmessage=freund.laden(getContext(),values[position]+".txt").split("////");
    String nachricht = lastmessage[lastmessage.length-1];
    message.setText(nachricht);                                                                 
    return element;
```

And here is my getView method of th used adapter.
Sorry if there are some grammar mistakes :)

Comment: That depends on your custom adapter implementation. Can you post your adapter code in your question?

Comment: Views has nothing to do with filter except accepting input . It's up to you what you trying to filter . Look for search in list view tutorials .